# Por que meu append (jQuery) está duplicando elementos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia.

Tenho o seguinte código.

```
// Inclui novo Container com seus elementos
$(document).on('click', 'ul[class^="inpt_"] li button[name="mais"]', function () {
    var i = 0;
    $('#gado ul[class^="inpt_"]').each(function () {
        var alvo = $(this).attr('class');
        alvo = alvo.replace('inpt_', '');
        alvo = parseInt(alvo, 10);
        if (alvo > i) {
            // Serve apenas para ver qual o elemento com maior número
            i = alvo;
        }
    });
    i++;

    $('#gado').append(
            "<div>" +
            "<ul class='inpt_" + i + "'>" +
            "<li><input name='boi[]' type='text' maxlength='50' placeholder='Num. do animal'></li>" +
            "<li><select class=\"verificar\" name='fk_boi[]'><option value=''>Aguardando...</option></select></li>" +
            "<li><input class=\"verificar\" type='number' name='peso[]' placeholder='Peso'></li>" +
            "<li><input class=\"verificar\" type='date' name='d_peso[]'></li>" +
            "<li><button type='button' name='mais'>+1</button></li>" +
            "<li><button type='button' name='inpt_" + i + "'>excluir este</button></li>" +
            "</ul>" +
            "<div class='cboth'></div>" +
            "</div>"
            );
});
```

Inicialmente ele cria um único elemento, mas dobra a quantidade a cada vez que a janela de diálogo a que ele está ligado abre. Na segunda vez ele adiciona dois do mesmo, na terceira vez que a janela abre ele cria três/quatro e assim vai.

Se eu limpo o cache do navegador, volta ao normal, mas não posso ficar pedindo isso pro cliente.

Alguma dica do que pode haver de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

De uma lida na documentação do jQuery sobre as funções [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) e [html](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html). A função `append()` adiciona o conteúdo após o último elemento, já a função `html()` define o conteúdo do elemento como aquele passado por parâmetro. Veja:

```
var elemento = "<i>teste</i>";

$("body").append(elemento); // <i>teste</i>
$("body").append(elemento); // <i>teste</i><i>teste</i>
$("body").append(elemento); // <i>teste</i><i>teste</i><i>teste</i>

$("body").html(elemento); // <i>teste</i>
```

Portanto, oque seu código está fazendo é adicionar uma nova div ao final do conteúdo toda vez que vc executa a função. Troque o append por html e seu código irá funcionar.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!

Comment: Boa tarde, @Lucas Deano. Obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento. No meu caso, eu preciso que seja adicionado aquele elemento ao final. O .html não me resolve. Trata-se de um formulário de venda onde o usuário vai acrescentando produtos conforme a necessidade.